# Shout I delete dynamic array in a function?

Tags: c++, dynamic

If I want my function return 2D array, I can write:

```
float **A(something){
    float **a;
    *operations here*
    return a;
}
```

My question is: should I delete dynamically allocated array a, or It will be deleted automatically after function returns a value?

Comment: it will not be deleted automatically.

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` to avoid trouble.

Comment: It will not be deleted automatically, nor should you delete it in this particular function as you are returning it.

Comment: There's nothing to delete. You haven't allocated anything.

Comment: This is C++, why are you using raw pointers and manual memory management for arrays?

Comment: So it is better to use vector type then raw pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No! If you delete the dynamically allocated **a** in your function, then all access by using **A** will be invalid, because the memory have been return to Operating System, all data will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "a" gets allocated in *operations here*, this function relies on the caller to delete/free it in whatever way matches the allocation.  This introduces some risk because these both have to happen, but they happen in different parts of the code, so if one part changes, or you use the function elsewhere, things can go wrong.

I recommend wrapping it in a class which will handle initializing and deleting the memory. You can then write operations in the class, and unit test them.

Comment: Yes, so I think vector would be the best here... to many problems with pointers.

Comment: @МихаилМихайловичГенкин So stop using them.

Comment: It could be derived from vector<vector<float>>

Comment: Heh, I also would say a vector is the way to go. It is relatively simple. Also, it looks like you are overusing (or is just test code) with pointers.